# MVC Views folder structure and application start up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, view

Since I have many views, I have created sub folders under the View folder of the MVC. eg

```
Views - Product
Views - Customer
Views - Orders
```

etc... Then each folder as related views to the entities. Things work Ok. The only problem is that when I debug my application - I mean running in debug mode - The URL is not working eg te URL will be like *Localhost:xxxx\Views\Product\Index* .... However If I click on real application links then things work ok ...

How can I make this work? ... it is giving me headache as every time I run the applicatiion the URL is wrong.

any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to Projects -> MyApplication Properties, then click the 'Web' tab. There you can change where the application runs from.

Comment: that is what it was. Much appreciated ... How can I mark it as answer?? ;-)

Comment: There is a greyed out tick under the voting on the left. Was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

That has to do with Visual Studio and the way it debugs web apps. You must've had focus on the view in the Solution Explorer, simply remove the focus from the view, placing focus on the web project will do, and it'll work as expected.